# Retrieving Session ID with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

For logging purposes, I'd like to create a logger that automatically adds the current session's ID to logged lines.
For logged in users this isn't a problem:

```
((WebAuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails())
    .getSessionId()
```

The problem is, before the user has logged in `getAuthentication()` returns `null`. Is there another way for getting the session ID without having a reference to the current response or anything of that sort?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You may use

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
```

This relies on Spring's `RequestContextHolder`, so it should be used with Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet` or you should have a `RequestContextListener` declared. Also session will be created if not exists.

Comment: @axtavt I have angular appli running in diffrnt port and server code is running in diffrnt port . In my server code has implemented spring security it redirecting to another java controller if success , in that i wrapped all user roles and other info . but  I am getting a only `anonymusUser` becuase in my redirecting url is not have cookie. is that overcome  your solution ..

Answer (score 9):

More easiest way is:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/foo")  
public void foo(HttpSession session) {  
    String sessionId = session.getId();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you visit this topic to find solution in WebSockets, maybe the following can be useful for you;

```
@MessageMapping("/message")
public void message(@Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) {
    // ...
}
```