# login a user programmatically with spring security in grails and returning sessionId

Tags: grails, spring-security

I’m writing the web service of a mobile application.

The application must authenticité
Actually my first approach was doing a post request on  **j_spring_security_check** with params :

j_username=myusername

j_password=mypassword

ajax=true

and getting back the sessionId by doing these change in the login controller

```
def ajaxSuccess = {     
    ....
    result.token  = springSecurityService.authentication.details.sessionId
    render( result as JSON)
}
```

Is there any other way to do the authentication programmatically and returning the sessionId using my own controller, so I can customize the authentication method (for example I want to update other parameter when I login)

Comment: check this out http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login

Comment: The better approach would be to implement your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler and do the custom work there, rather than re-writing the entire auth procedure.  See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/7%20Events.html

Answer (score 0):

If the extra parameters rely on user input, you'll almost certainly have to provide a custom login. If those parameters will be managed apart from the user, I don't see why you can't do that in a controller class by populating a custom user details object. At the same time, you could get the session ID via `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()` (shamelessly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542026/retrieving-session-id-with-spring-security)).

Comment: yes @cabbagery , the extra parameters rely on user input , but i can't figure out how to make the custom login , and that's why i want to login and get the sessionId programmatically

Comment: I suspect you should be fairly easily able to build a log-in page with the custom parameters, have it submit to a controller, and redirect the request (with the login credentials) to the actual authentication handler. You should in fact be able to do this both ways -- handle the extra parameters first and login second, or login first and handle the extra parameters second. The session id shouldn't be the stumbling block here, but I may not fully understand your needs.