# What is the Best way to group log messages in a MVC app

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I want to add a logging system to our spring MVC application with minimum refactoring. I want to group messages per request and attach some `id` to it. One approach I thought of is, creating some logger object with an `id` in controller and pass to service, DAO layers. All the layers keep adding messages to that logger object. Finally, I print them at the end of request processing. Does Spring or log4j frameworks provide any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a Request scope, so you can create an request-scoped ID object generated when a request is received. You can then inject this object in the classes you need to log with regular dependency injection, so you don't have to pass anything around.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public RequestId requestScopedBean() {
    return new RequestId();
}
```

As for the Log, the common practice is to initialise a Log per class. Then you'd have all the elements you want in every class.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.java)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has a feature to add SessionId to the logger automatically . 
[Check this One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542026/retrieving-session-id-with-spring-security)

Posting the same answer here :

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
```

This relies on Spring's RequestContextHolder, so it should be used with Spring MVC's DispatcherServlet or you should have a RequestContextListener declared. Also session will be created if not exists.